# Qunit acceptance test for Ember.JS app passing in browser but failing in CLI via PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, phantomjs, qunit

I'm working through the [Ember-CLI-101 ebook](https://leanpub.com/ember-cli-101) and have a small issue, I've gotten around to writing acceptance (integration/feature) tests and I've got a test that goes to the root path and then click a link on the header and then fill in a form.

It works when I go to http://localhost:4200/tests but when I do `ember test` in the CLI it fails with the following error:

```
actual: >
false
expected: >
true
message: >
Error: Element a[href="/friends/new"] not found.
Log: >
```

I assume this is some kind of PhantomJS issue with the page not loading properly but it could be anything I suppose.  I'm having a hard time finding a solution on the web and would appreciate any help please.

The test:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from '../../helpers/start-app';

var application;

module('Acceptance | friends/new', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('creating a new friend', function(assert){
  visit('/');
  click('a[href="/friends/new"]');

  andThen(function(){
    assert.equal(currentPath(), 'friends.new');
  });
  fillIn('input[placeholder="First Name"]', 'Johnny');
  fillIn('input[placeholder="Last Name"]', 'Cash');
  fillIn('input[placeholder="email"]', 'j@cash.com');
  fillIn('input[placeholder="twitter"]', 'jcash');
  click('input[value="Save"]');

  andThen(function(){
    assert.equal(
      currentRouteName(),
      'friends.show.index',
      'Redirects to friends.show after create'
    );
  });
});
```

This is the header on the page:

```
<nav>
  {{link-to "Ember-Borrowers" "index" class="main"}}

  <input id="bmenu" class="burgercheck" type="checkbox">
  <label for="bmenu" class="burgermenu"></label>

  <div class="menu">
    {{link-to "Dashboard" "index" class="icon-gauge"}}
    {{link-to "Friends" "friends" class="icon=users-1"}}
    {{link-to "New Friend" "friends.new" class="icon-user-add"}}
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is the HTML generated:

```
<a id="ember471" class="ember-view icon-user-add" href="/friends/new">New Friend</a>
```

As I say, it passes in the browser.

EDIT:

What confuses me is that the below test works fine, also clicking on a link.  The difference is that this link is in the body whereas the above (failing) test's link is in the header:

```
test('clicking save without filling fields', function(assert){
  visit('/friends/new');
  click('input[value="Save"]');

  andThen(function(){
    assert.equal(
      currentRouteName(),
      'friends.new',
      'Stays on new page'
    );
    assert.equal(
      find("h2:contains(You have to fill in all the fields)").length,
      1,
      "displays error message"
    );
  });
});
```

EDIT 2:

I tried putting a link in the body of the index.html just to test if it's the header (navbar) but it still doesn't work.  I used `<a href="/friends/new" class="icon-user-add"></a>` and still got `Error: Element a[href="/friends/new"] not found.`

EDIT 3:

[My Git repo is here](https://github.com/sanjsanj/ember-borrowers)

Comment: if you grab the parent element and dump it's .html() property what do you see? I've found in some situations chrome will put the "type" of a button as "submit" when phantom won't and I literally saw the html was different between the 2 runtimes

Comment: Sorry but how would I console.log the parent element?  I've tried `console.log(application.html());` and it gives me nothing, and `console.log($('html'));` gives me the test page's html not the app's.

Comment: You can grab the parent of the href but if it isn't "selector friendly" you might need to grab the div for the outter context. One selector you might use would be $('input[value="Save"]').parent().html()